# Hosting ASP.NET MVC in a non-root URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application in .NET 4.5.2. The application is working fine in my local IIS Express. I use FTP deployment to deploy the application in a physical folder such that URL of the ASP.NET application will be:

```
http://www.example.com/level1/level2/
```

The main site at: `http://www.example.com` is a non-ASP site with static HTMLs.

Unfortunately, when I goto `http://www.example.com/level1/level2/` I get:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
>   The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Which tells me IIS is not treating it as a ASP.NET MVC folder.

My `RouteConfig.cs` has:

```
routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Default",
              url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "SampleController", action ="Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Is there something I need to do in my Route such that 
`http://www.example.com/level1/level2/` will work like an ASP.NET MVC site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run any ASP.NET application (including ASP.NET MVC) on IIS, the virtual directory the application hosted in must be configured as an **IIS Application**.

By default when you add a Web Site to IIS, it makes the root virtual directory into an IIS Application. However, this is not the default when you have a subdirectory of a Web Site - you have to enable this feature manually.

1. In IIS Manager, expand the local computer and Sites folder, and keep drilling until you reach the directory.
2. Right-click the virtual directory and click **Convert to Application**.

Reference: [How to: Create and Configure Virtual Directories and Applications in IIS 7.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thank you. This was indeed the case. The site is hosted through SmartASP.Net and they confirmed that I need to add the folder as ASP.NET application.